# Russell-Whitehead-infinity and the axiom of infinity

Tags: set-theory, infinity

Let us work in $\mathsf{ZF-Inf}$, i.e. Zermelo-Frankel without the Axiom of Choice and without the axiom of infinity. For each set $A$, say that $F$ is *an inductive family of subsets of $A$* iff $\varnothing \in F$ and, if $x \in F$ and $y \in A$, then $x \cup \{y\} \in F$. Define a set to be RW-finite iff it is contained in every inductive family of its subsets. It is RW-infinite iff it is not RW-finite.

> **Question:** Suppose there is an RW-infinite set. Is it the case that $\mathsf{ZF-Inf}$ can prove, given this hypothesis, that there is a set $W$ such that $\varnothing \in W$ and, if $x \in W$, then $x \cup \{x\} \in W$? In other words, does the existence of an RW-infinite set imply the axiom of infinity in its usual formulation?

I can prove that the axiom of infinity implies the existence of an RW-infinite set, but I'm not having much luck proving this converse... any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is provable.

Specifically, suppose $A$ is RW-infinite. Let $f:\mathcal{P}(A)\rightarrow Ord$ send $X$ to the unique ordinal in bijection with $X$ if such exists, and to $0$ otherwise. By replacement, $ran(f)$ is a set; by RW-infiniteness of $A$, it contains every finite ordinal. From this we can extract $\omega$.

Note that this crucially used replacement. I believe this is necessary, but I don't immediately see how to build a witnessing model (that is, a model of $\mathsf{Z-Inf+\neg Inf+RWInf}$).

Comment: How do you use the RW-infiniteness of $A$ to show that it contains every finite ordinal?

Comment: It's easy to show that $A$ itself can't be in bijection with a finite ordinal if $A$ is RW-infinite. Now suppose $ran(f)$ doesn't contain every finite ordinal. Let $n+1$ be the least finite ordinal not in $ran(f)$. Fix $X\subseteq A$ with $f(X)=n$. Since $A$ is RW-infinite, there is some $a\in A\setminus X$. But then $f(X\cup\{a\})=n+1$, a contradiction with the assumption that $n+1\not\in ran(f)$.

Comment: Very nice! Thanks!